# convert type `Any` to type `Map` in scala

Tags: scala

How can I convert type `Any` to type `Map` in scala?

Right now I have this val:

```
poop: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(scenario0 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki), scenario1 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki))
```

I am trying to extract the `Map` objects associated with `scenario0` and `scenario1` and pass these maps into a function.

Comment: only as a side note: you shouldn't have a Map[String, Any]. If you can avoid that, make an effort

Comment: Regard to previous question he couldn't. It's inbound data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1) You can cast `Any` to `Map[A, B]`.**

example, following is `Map` of `String to another Map`

```
scala> val mapping : Map[String, Any] = Map("key1" -> Map ("key1.1" -> "value1"), "key2" -> Map("key1.2" -> 100))
mapping: Map[String,Any] = Map(key1 -> Map(key1.1 -> value1), key2 -> Map(key1.2 -> 100))

scala> mapping("key1")
res1: Any = Map(key1.1 -> value1)
```

to cast `Any` to `Map[A, B]`

```
scala> mapping("key1").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
res3: Map[String,Any] = Map(key1.1 -> value1)
```

Then pass to the function

```
scala> def processSomething(mapping: Map[String, Any]) = println(mapping.keys)
processSomething: (mapping: Map[String,Any])Unit

scala> processSomething(mapping("key1").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
Set(key1.1)
```

**2) Another way is match the result of `mainMap("key")`**.

This way, you can handle a case when the result somehow is not `Map`. (*With casting it throws class cast exception.*)

Example below

```
mapping("key1") match {
  case valueMap : Map[String, Any] => processSomething(valueMap)
  case _ => println("key1 is not Map")
}
```

Comment: It seems keys doesn't matter and function always the same. `poop.values.map(x => f(x.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]))`

Comment: Agree, thats the best way to do it if I want to process all the keys. cc @Liondancer

Comment: What I was looking for was `.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]` Thanks for the thorough answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key <- myMap.keySet) myFunc(myMap(key))
```

Comment: Error: type mismatch;
 found   : `Any`
 required: `Map[_,_]`